# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 Unable to parse results from evaluateTransaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Using Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 as of, I'm trying to evaluate a transaction result like so:

```
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('evm');

        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract('cc');

        const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('getEVMAddress') ;
```

And the getEVMAddress function is defined as follows:

```
  async getEVMAddress(stub) {
    console.info('============= START : getEVMAddress ===========');


    const evmAsBytes = await stub.getState('EVMADDRESS'); 
    if (!evmAsBytes || evmAsBytes.length === 0) {
        throw new Error(`EVMADDRESS does not exist`);
    }

    var evmAddress = JSON.parse(evmAsBytes);

    console.info('============= END : getEVMAddress ===========');

    return JSON.stringify(evmAddress);


  }
```

Which is storing a single simple string. I don't know what's happening, I already tried decoding with BlockDecoder but I seem unable to query results outside the ledger. Do note that there are no errors if we brint the string from inside the chain code, its results are just fine, but outside the chain code I only receive a Buffer with extraneous data within which I'm unable to parse correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to send the string back from a Buffer with `Buffer.from(string)`

Answer (score 0):

while retrieving data from the ledger you will by default receive buffered data which you must covert to string.

Try to convert your output to string using toString() method.

var s= result.toString(). // converts buffer to string.

After that use var object = JSON.parse(s). //converts your string to JSON object.

Finally you can view a specific column of EVM table using,

var c= s['coulmn_name']; //column name is the name of the column in your record that you want in your EVM table.